# fire image pixel when order vale is more than $600 through Google Tag Manager

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I have a restaurant website and i want to sell a specific dish. People can update the quantity of dish they want to order. Quantity gets updated without browser refresh. I want to send an image pixel to GTM (google tag manager version 2) when the order value is more than $50 and the quantity is more than 10 (i want this to be fired every time the quantity is updated and meets the minimum order value requirement). What code should I put in the website and how should i configure the variable.triggers/tags for this.
Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks,
Gill

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your site. In general, you should use a custom HTML tag to check quantity and sum. This tag should be fired, for example, with any click on refresh button or with blure on some fields. This HTML tag should add an event to dataLayer when all condition are met. This event you can use in a rule to fire your pixel tag.